# jQuery - <option> tag - Cannot fire callback on <option> 'deselect' or 'focusout'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/t9fmA/1/ - Demo

Hi,

I've got a `<select>` + `<option>` list that, if the user selects **Other**, an input box appears below. This part works fine, as I use the `.click()` function on the `<option>`. However, I want the input box to disappear once we chose something other than **Other**.

I tried `.blur()` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Here is the HTML

```
<label for="product">Product: </label>
<select id="product">
    <option value="">375 ml</option>
    <option value="">500 ml</option>
    <option value="">750 ml</option>
    <option value="">1 L</option>
    <option value="">1.1 L</option>
    <option value="">1.5 L</option>
    <option value="" class="product-other-switch">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="product-other-div" style="display: none;">
    <label for="product-other">Specify:</label>
    <input type="text" id="product-other" />
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-other-switch').click(function() {
        $('.product-other-div').slideDown('fast');
    });

    $('.product-other-switch').blur(function() {
       alert('Handler for .blur() called.'); 
    });
});
```

And of course, you can try the jsfiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/t9fmA/1/

Comment: Try to attach `onchange` listener to `#product`. If the selected index is not the last one, hide the div. You can also use this same handler to show the div, since click detection on a single `option` is not cross-browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try with values

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9fmA/2/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="product">
    <option value="1">375 ml</option>
    <option value="2">500 ml</option>
    <option value="3">750 ml</option>
    <option value="4">1 L</option>
    <option value="5">1.1 L</option>
    <option value="6">1.5 L</option>
    <option value="" class="product-other-switch">Other</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#product').change(function() {
        dropdown = $('#product').val();
        if (dropdown === '')
            $('.product-other-div').slideDown('fast'); 
        else
            $('.product-other-div').slideUp('fast');

    });
});
```

Comment: OK, after testing, this is the option which works in Chrome / Safari as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
Give a value to `option` other (Like this)

```
<select id="product">
    <option value="">375 ml</option>
    <option value="">500 ml</option>
    <option value="">750 ml</option>
    <option value="">1 L</option>
    <option value="">1.1 L</option>
    <option value="">1.5 L</option>
    <option value="other" class="product-other-switch">Other</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("select#product").click(function(){
if($(this).val() == "other")
{
// fade in your text box ;
}
else
{
// fade out your text box ;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well typically for something like this I would use the change event and compare values, however, you can use the following selector for clicking off the other to work with your code:

```
$("#product option:not(.product-other-switch)").click(function() {
    $(".product-other-div").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Comment: @all - Thanks all, all your answers work. I choose tymeJV's because it's the one that I can relate to most.